# Поиск по словам из list

Tags: python

```
name = 'Корова на столе'
last = '~'

inp = 'Корова + столе'.replace(' ', '').split('+')
if any(x.lower() in name.lower() for x in inp):
    print(name)
```

Тут мой код и как мне сделать так чтобы он брал только тогда когда в `name` указано все 2 слова из `inp` а если

`name = 'Корова'` чтоб он пропускал

и еще один вариант

```
name = 'Корова'
last = 'на столе'

inp = 'Корова + столе'.replace(' ', '').split('+')
```

Если допустим что в `name` и `last` есть эти два слова он должен братьк

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать пересечение множеств

```
name = 'Корова на столе'
inp = 'Корова + столе'.replace(' ', '').split('+')
if len(set(inp).intersection(name.split())) == len(inp):
    print(name)
```

Если нужно регистронезависимое сравнение, код нужно модифицировать, приведя строки к одному регистру